# databricks - no response when executing command in terminal 'export DATABRICKS_CONFIG_FILE="dbfs:/FileStore/tables/partition.csv'

Tags: azure, databricks

I am trying to export the csv file by following this guide https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/index.html , but there's no response when executing below command, it looks like exist the command directly without saying exporting is successfully or failed.

I have finished install the cli and setup authentication by entering a host and token in mac terminal by following the guide as well.

```
export DATABRICKS_CONFIG_FILE="dbfs:/FileStore/tables/partition.csv"
```

please refer to this screenshot:
[image]
At first, I write the dataframe into file system by below code

df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").csv("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/partition.csv")

how could i successfully export the file from databricks and where does it stored locally?

**screenShot:**
[image]

Comment: hi @peace. Are you using Databricks on any cloud platform (specify it)? Or is it Community edition?

Comment: hi @SaiVamsi, It's azure databricks,  not community edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can copy to your local machine or move to another destination as needed

**Configure azure CLI with azure databricks:**

Please follow this steps:

- `pip install databricks-cli`
- Use `databricks configure --token` command
- Mention Azure databricks **host name**: `https://adb-xxxxx.azuredatabricks.net/`
- Past your Personal **Access Token**.

[image]

Now all set to export the CSV file and store it in a destination location.

```
databricks fs cp dbfs:/FileStore/tables/partition.csv dbfs:/destination/your_folder/file.csv

databricks fs cp C:/folder/file.csv dbfs:/FileStore/folder
```

**Or**

If you have a lot of CSV files placed in a folder .you prefer to export the entire folder rather than individual files.

Use `-r` to select your folder instead of the individual file.

```
databricks fs cp -r  dbfs:/<folder>  destination/folder
```

**Alternative approach in python:**

You can use directly `dbutils.fs.cp("dbfs:/FileStore/gender_submission.csv","destination/folder")`

Comment: Hi @SaiVamsi - I am trying the last approach you suggested. when I run this dbutils.fs.cp() in notebook, it return "True" to me, but the file is not copyed to the destination folder when i check the result.   When I run this in mac terminal, i always got error "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token" do you have any idea?

Comment: hi @peace, alternative approach it is in python ,   use `%python
 dbutils.fs.cp("dbfs:/FileStore/gender_submission.csv","destination/folder")`

Comment: Hi @SaiVamsi - could you please help check the last screenShot in this post i uploaded just now?  Do you mean run it in that way in databricks->notebook? the run result is True, but I still can't see the copied file in the destinated folder I specified in the command.

Comment: yes its correct, check your destination/folder location . if you got again same issue. Please refer this  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4L064NfMV0&t=477s) configuring azure databricks with your workspace.